# RStudio & RGoogleAnalytics giving Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: r, google-analytics

I am trying to connect to google analytics from R through Analytics API. Following is my code.

```
library(RGoogleAnalytics)

oauth_token <- Auth(client.id = "clientID", client.secret = "clientSecret")
```

When I run above command it gives me following error in browser

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:1410/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
```

I have following settings in google developer console

```
Authorised JavaScript origins : http://localhost:1410
Authorised redirect URIs: http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your redirect URIs to the same port.

http://localhost:1410/oauth2callback

If that does not work, create a new client secret json file. Use "other" as the application type;

Comment: Its not working. Is there anything else I am missing on?